# How to write a model class for json string response in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, retrofit

Hi I am new to android,

I have worked with regular json object response but now I have been asked to work with json string response like this,

```
"{\"message\":\"OTP is sent to your Mobile number and Email id\",\"status\":true,\"existing_user\":true}"
```

I have no idea how to call API's with this response. I searched how to do it and found nothing. Please help me if anyone knows how to get it done.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for network calls you can use Retrofit.

Then you can convert your JSON response to java class with this site
[Json to java](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

For example, your JSON is converted to the below class

```
public class Output{

public String message;
public Boolean status;
public Boolean existingUser;

}
```

Comment: It's the traditional method right? but it doesn't work with this kind of response . I tried it. It throws "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException in android" . I don't know what's wrong

Comment: You need to delete "\" characters in json to avoid getting this exception

Comment: And also please don't forget to delete " character from start and end of JSON

Comment: I understand it now . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;

@SerializedName("existing_user")
@Expose
private Boolean existingUser;

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

public Boolean getExistingUser() {
return existingUser;
}

public void setExistingUser(Boolean existingUser) {
this.existingUser = existingUser;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a Modal class is

1. go to https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org
2. paste your JSON data and select format.
3. and click on preview.